# Affectiva C# SDK crashes

Tags: c#, opencv, runtime-error, affdex-sdk

I just started using Affectiva SDK for C#, and after a few runs, I stumbled upon a continuous crash problem.
I am using the Camera processing, on x86 architecture and .Net 4.5.1. I have VS 2013 installed. My OS is Windows 10. I have added "opencv_ffmpeg248" and "affdex-native" in my output.
The code builds and runs ok, but from time to time, during runtime, it throws this errors and the application closes.

This is the code that I am using:

```
 public class Class1 : Affdex.ImageListener
{
    private Affdex.CameraDetector _detector;

    public event EventHandler<string[]> AllValuesEvent;

    public Class1()
    {
        _detector = new Affdex.CameraDetector();
        _detector.setDetectAllEmotions(true);
        _detector.setDetectAllAppearances(true);

        String classifierPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Affectiva\Affdex SDK\data";
        _detector.setClassifierPath(classifierPath);
        _detector.setImageListener(this);
        _detector.start();
    }

    public void StopCamera()
    {
        _detector.stop();
    }


    public void onImageCapture(Frame frame)
    {

    }

    public void onImageResults(Dictionary<int, Face> faces, Frame frame)
    {
        if (faces.Count > 0)
        {
            Face face = faces.First().Value;

            Console.WriteLine("Age: {0} Gender: {1} Glasses: {2}",
                face.Appearance.Age,
                face.Appearance.Gender,
                face.Appearance.Glasses);

            string[] names = new string[8];
            string[] values = new string[8];

            names[0] = "Anger";
            names[1] = "Contempt";
            names[2] = "Disgust";
            names[3] = "Engagement";
            names[4] = "Fear";
            names[5] = "Joy";
            names[6] = "Sadness";
            names[7] = "Surprise";

            values[0] = face.Emotions.Anger.ToString("F2");
            values[1] = face.Emotions.Contempt.ToString("F2");
            values[2] = face.Emotions.Disgust.ToString("F2");
            values[3] = face.Emotions.Engagement.ToString("F2");
            values[4] = face.Emotions.Fear.ToString("F2");
            values[5] = face.Emotions.Joy.ToString("F2");
            values[6] = face.Emotions.Sadness.ToString("F2");
            values[7] = face.Emotions.Surprise.ToString("F2");

            RaiseAllValuesEvent(names, values);
        }
    }

    private void RaiseAllValuesEvent(string[] names, string[] values)
    {
        if (AllValuesEvent != null)
        {
            AllValuesEvent(names, values);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors that appear:
[image]
[image]

Anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, One problem might be that you are mixing debug and release DLLs .. Can you make sure that you import the DLLs that match your build profile.

Comment: Well, apparently, your suggestion seems to have solved my problem.

I will continue monitoring it for the next few days to see if I still get the error using the release dlls and come back with the result.

Comment: hello,

@ahamino your suggestion fixed my problem. Thank you. I don`t know how to flag your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this here, to be able to mark as answer, and to have this topic closed.

As suggested by @ahamino in a comment, the issue was the fact that I have accidentally mixed debug dlls into my references. Adding only release dlls fixed my issue.

Thank you again @ahamino.